# Selectively allow some urls through Rack::Auth::Basic

Tags: ruby, rack

I've set up a blog that I'd like to be minimally secured (i.e., I just want to keep out random people I don't know, I'm not trying to implement NSA-like security measures). I'm using [toto](http://cloudhead.io/toto) with Rack::Auth::Basic to "secure" the site. I'd like to let through `index.xml` so that blog readers will be able to read the feed without dealing with password (and yes, I know that this is a big hole in my "security").

How do I let through this one url with Rack::Auth::Basic?

This is how I added basic auth to my site:

```
use Rack::Auth::Basic, "blog" do |username, password|
  [username, password] == ['generic', 'stupidanddumbpassword']
end
```

Comment: Have you considered using Rack::URLMap? [This](http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/rack-urlmap-and-kicking-ass) is a pretty good blog post on using it. I'm not sure it will work for you though. If you only want certain people to see something then either more security or just plain ol' email would be my suggestion (just a suggestion, mind :)

Answer (score 21):

How about some good ol' fashioned inheritance? Rack::Auth::Basic is a simple rack app (source: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/auth/basic.rb), so it's possible to override the #call method and skip authentication when the request path matches '/index.xml':

```
class BlogAuth < Rack::Auth::Basic

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    case request.path
    when '/index.xml'
      @app.call(env)  # skip auth
    else
      super           # perform auth
    end
  end

end

use BlogAuth, "blog" do |username, password|
  [username, password] == ['generic', 'stupidanddumbpassword']
end
```

For more background on rack, check out: http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html

I haven't tried @Iain's suggestion about Rack::URLMap, but it looks like it could also be a good option.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the answer!

I used this solution too, but made a small change.
because the current solution will probably result in a duplication of code if an app will require more then one path to be accessible, 
I changed the code to:

```
class AppBasicAuth < Rack::Auth::Basic
  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    allowed_paths = ['/api/v2/get_new.json']

    if allowed_paths.include? request.path
        @app.call(env)  # skip auth
    else
      super           # perform auth
    end
 end
end
```